# LLVM: How to create char array reference

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I am trying to implement an opt pass that will compress string constants in ROM and then, at the cost of CPU + RAM, re-materialize the values at runtime. Before implementing compression, I just want to place all strings in a table, and do a lookup.

Example:

```
printf("Hello");
```

Would become the equivalent of

```
char placeholder[6];
int strID = 0;
tableLookup(placeholder, 0 /*ID*/); // Fill array
printf(placeholder);
```

The LLVM IR I was able to generate looks like the following:

```
%fakeString = alloca [10 x i8], align 1
call void @llvm.dbg.declare(metadata [10 x i8]* %fakeString, metadata !60, metadata !25), !dbg !64
%arraydecay = getelementptr inbounds [10 x i8], [10 x i8]* %fakeString, i32 0, i32 0, !dbg !65
call void @tableLookup(i8* %arraydecay, i32 0) #2, !dbg !66
```

How would I be able to create this programatically? The two main pieces I am missing:
1. How to create the array reference (after creating the alloca instruction)
2. How to get result from tableLookup and replace the operand in the old printf()

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: The table loop up function would store the string in the memory pointed by arraydecay. You can use that directly to all printf.

Comment: The table lookup function takes memory and fills it with strings stored in ROM. The memory needs to be part of whichever function it's used in, otherwise it's no longer part of the stack when you return. The question, however, was how can I create the getelementptr and how to replace an operand of a function